# Spark IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE

Tags: apache-spark

I have a PySpark program that is doing fairly simple data conversion on a large number of records. I sporadically get the following error. I've added code to make sure none of the IntegerType values that I write are out of the normal 32-bit integer value range. This out of range integer seems to be some internal value, not something I pass in.

This happens on a simple call to count. The Python line that triggers this error is very simple:

```
data_frame_count = data_frame.count()
```

I am running this on Spark 2.0 under Amazon EMR 5.0.

I've done a search on this error. I see another conversation thread that is focused on fancier logistic regression processing. Here, I am doing, very simple, load data, basic parsing/cleaning of data, and writing out data.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:869)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore$$anonfun$getBytes$2.apply(DiskStore.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore$$anonfun$getBytes$2.apply(DiskStore.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1287)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.getBytes(DiskStore.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$$doGetLocalBytes(BlockManager.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$getLocalBytes$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$getLocalBytes$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:475)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getLocalBytes(BlockManager.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getBlockData(BlockManager.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer$$anonfun$2.apply(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer$$anonfun$2.apply(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer.receive(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:158)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:106)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:119)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Use `repartition`method to smaller partitions size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is an open issue for it...

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1476

From the description:

> underlying abstraction for blocks in spark is a ByteBuffer : which limits the size of the block to 2GB.
>   This has implication not just for managed blocks in use, but also for shuffle blocks (memory mapped blocks are limited to 2gig, even though the api allows for long), ser-deser via byte array backed outstreams (SPARK-1391), etc.
>   This is a severe limitation for use of spark when used on non trivial datasets.