# Spark dataframe repartition by expression versus 2GB limit

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We all know spark does not support partitions bigger than 2GB. (we get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE` when this happens)

So, how do we increase the number of partitions when partitionning by an expression using `df.repartition(num, $"col")` ?  Here, any value of `num` will not prevent busting the 2GB limit if the `col` hashes to the same partition.

Dataframes cannot have a custom hash partitioner as we do with rdds. Some effort is made to have Range partitionner but that does not help here.

What I've found so far is to use window operations in order to generate a custom made partitioning column:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val wSpec = Window.partitionBy("col").orderBy($"col")
val maxRecords = 100000
val tempDF = df.withColumn("hash_part", concat_ws("-", $"col", (row_number().over(wSpec) / lit(maxRecords)).cast("int")))

val out = tempDF.repartition($"hash_part").drop("hash_part")
```

Do you have a better solution?  More elegant? More Performant?

Related (but do not answer) SO posts:

- [How to define partitioning of DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995699/how-to-define-partitioning-of-dataframe)
- [Why does Spark RDD partition has 2GB limit for HDFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689719/why-does-spark-rdd-partition-has-2gb-limit-for-hdfs)
- [Why does FileChannel.map take up to Integer.MAX_VALUE of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076472/why-does-filechannel-map-take-up-to-integer-max-value-of-data?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Spark IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281610/spark-illegalargumentexception-size-exceeds-integer-max-value)

Comment: If `row_number().over(wSpec)` works for you , then you don't really have a problem - it already repartitions your data.